# Как связать два элемента с помощью data-атрибутов?

Tags: jquery

Имею два элемента:

```
<button class="btn_delete js-btnDelete active" data-id="delete"></button>
```

и

```
<button class="buy-it js-btnBasket" data-id="delete"></button>
```

При клике на один должен удалиться другой. 
Пытаюсь разобраться, как это сделать через data-атрибуты.
Добавил обоим data-id="delete"

В jQ пишу:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.js-btnDelete', function() {
   $(this).attr('delete').removeClass('active');
 });
```

Но, не получаю то, что нужно.
Помогите разораться. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.buy-it', function() {
  $(`span[data-id="${$(this).attr('data-id')}"`).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-id="1" class="buy-it js-btnBasket">Тест 1</button>
<button data-id="2" class="buy-it js-btnBasket">Тест 2</button>
<button data-id="3" class="buy-it js-btnBasket">Тест 3</button>
<button data-id="4" class="buy-it js-btnBasket">Тест 4</button>
<hr>

<span data-id="1">Тест 1</span>
<span data-id="2">Тест 2</span>
<span data-id="3">Тест 3</span>
<span data-id="4">Тест 4</span>
```

Comment: Ок, подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю, что для того, чтобы это работало, я имею ввиду связь, нужно обязательно поставить одинаковый data-id="delete" на оба элемента. Тогда они будут считаться связанными, так?

Comment: https://codepen.io/iliyasold/pen/JjPQKRr

Comment: @IliyaV.Soldatkin, нет. Это просто пользовательские аттребуты. Связываете их вы, при помощи js.

Comment: Каким образом это происходит, например? Как их связать?)

Comment: @IliyaV.Soldatkin так я вам и ответил) Ответ посмотрите.

Comment: Ок, а если таких пар сотни? То как именно при нажатии на 
<button class="btn_delete js-btnDelete active" data-id="delete">Жми чтобы удалить "Тест"</button> будет выбрана та, которую следует удалить?

Comment: @IliyaV.Soldatkin подправил

Comment: Спасибо огромное тебе!!!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял фразу "При клике на один должен удалиться другой", то я бвы делал как-то так - убирал бы все с data = delete кроме нажатого

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-id="delete"]'); 
[].forEach.call(buttons, (e => e.onclick = function() {
   me = this;
   [].forEach.call(buttons, function(e) {
       if(e !== me) 
           e.style.display = 'none'
    })
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn_delete js-btnDelete active" data-id="delete">Жми чтобы удалить "Тест"</button>
<button class="buy-it js-btnBasket" data-id="delete">Тест</button>
```

Comment: Не совсем правильно выразился, извините) При клике на один элемент должен удалиться класс active в другом элементе, так, как там и написано. Просто мне хочется понять, как именно связать эти два элемента между собой, используя data-атрибуты. Если я правильно понимаю, нужно обоим прописать одинаковые data-id="delete"? Или нет?